# I need help removing items from listbox and loading different set of items from a file

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Ok, so I'm working on an automated browser using cefsharp on winforms C#. I am currently loading 150 URLs into a listbox from a file on my pc and it is working just fine. What I need is to load a different text file into the listbox after it's done, and then a different one and so on.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Links1.txt");
            listbox1.Items.AddRange(lines);
```

I have that on a button and it and then I have the code to load the urls, if you need to see that let me know. So what I need to do after that is load Links2.txt and then Links3.txt, and so on in total there's 264 text files.

Please let me know if there's a better way of doing this and if so how? Thank you.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're already successfully removing all the existing items from the list box for Links1.txt before you load Links2.txt. You're just asking for a better a way of doing it?

Comment: May be a better fit for Code Review SE

Comment: @Adrian Yeah, I can successfully remove Links1.txt and add Links2.txt but the way I'm doing it is going to take me a long time to do it to the other 262 text files...

Comment: Well, providing code that does that actual does what you say would be start if you are after help. But I also agree with @EJoshuaS, that this question may be better suited to [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as you have working code that you want to make better.

Comment: Alright I'll post it there, do I just delete this post then?

Comment: Yes just delete it. :) Saves the mods some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what I need to do after that is load Links2.txt and then Links3.txt, and so on in total there's 264 text files.

Use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 265;i++)
{
     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Links" + i.ToString() + ".txt");
     listbox1.Items.AddRange(lines);

     //Load the listbox items into cefsharp
     ...
}
```